# Raspberry pi not connecting to monitor

Tags: hdmi, screen, lcd

I am using raspberry pi 4 B+ with dell monitor DEL-DELL_E228WFP. But it shows auto detect(digital input) and keeps going to black screen when I move the cursor. Also it goes to power save a lot and sleeps.

Connection method:
DVI-D to HDMI adaptor and HDMI to mini HDMI cable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was with the power circuit in the monitor, all DELL_E228WFP were defective with that issue. So I replaced on of the components and now is working fine.